# Bash csv delete line if previous line matches

Tags: bash, awk

I have a csv file like so:

```
"a", "b", "c" 
"1", "b", "4"
"3", "g", "f"
```

Wherever `"b"` appears in the same place as the second column value in two consecutive lines, I want to delete the second line, thus resulting in:

```
"a", "b", "c" 
"3", "g", "f"
```

This at least gets me started with the parsing:

```
awk -F "," '$1' file.csv
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This deletes a line any time that the second column is a repeat:

```
$ awk -F, '$2==last{next} {last=$2} 1' file.csv
"a", "b", "c" 
"3", "g", "f"
```

#### How it works

- `$2==last{next}`

  If the second column, `$2`, is equal to the previous second column, `last`, then skip this and go to the `next` line.
- `last=$2`

  Update the value of `last`.
- `1`

  This is cryptic shorthand for "print the line".

#### Variation 1

If we only want to delete lines that have the second column equal to `"b"` when that is a repeat of the previous line, then:

```
awk -F, '$2==last && $2==" \"b\"" {next} {last=$2} 1' file.csv
```

#### Variation 2

Suppose that we only want to remove the lines every second occurrence of a `"b"`:

```
awk -F, '$2==last && $2==" \"b\"" {last="";next} {last=$2} 1' file.csv
```

#### Variation 3

Suppose we want to skip any line with second column of `"b"` if it is followed by a line with the same second column.  Then:

```
awk -F, '$2==last && $2==" \"b\"" {line=$0;next} NR>1{print line} {last=$2;line=$0} END{print line}' file.csv
```

Comment: Wow, magnificent! - Although I believe he only wants to remove the lines every second occurrence. - I wish I could give 10 votes to this answer.

Comment: @ShellFish Thank you much.  Your "every second occurrence." interpretation is interesting.  I added a variation to do that.

Comment: The last one says: if the last is the same as this and they both equal "b" then make the last null, then skip to the next; then update last to be this current one. What does update last mean?

Comment: In reference to this: $ awk -F, '$2==last{next} {last=$2} 1' file.csv, how would you skip the first occurrence rather than the second one?

Comment: @compguy24  (1) _"What does update last mean?"_  `last` is the name of an awk variable that is used to hold a value from a previous line.  "update last" means to assign `last` to a new value.  (2)  _"...then skip to the next; then update last to be this current one."_  It doesn't happen in that way.  If the conditions are met to "skip to the next", then no more commands are executed before `awk` starts over _from the beginning_ on the next line.   Thus, if "skip to the next" happens, then the "update last to be this current one" is not executed for this line.

Comment: @compguy24 Please clarify: if you want to skip the first occurrence, do you want to skip it only if there is a second occurrence?  What do you want to happen if there is a third occurrence in a row?

Comment: @John1024 I want to skip/delete it only if there is a second occurrence. There are no third occurrences.

Comment: @compguy24 OK.  I just added that as "variation 3" in the answer.

Comment: so i've modified the script to take out the first instance of min==00 in this: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/9252d426924de85682ba14e55711ef05/cop31.csv but it is not having the desired effect. here is how i modified the script: awk -F, '$5==last && $5==" \"00\"" {line=$0;next} NR>1{print line} {last=$5;line=$0} END{print line}'

Comment: @compguy24 The file `cop31.csv` has a different format than the one in the question.  In particular, it does not have spaces after commas.  (Yes, that kind of stuff makes a difference to computers.)  Try: `awk -F, '$5==last && $5=="\"00\"" {line=$0;next} NR>1{print line} {last=$5;line=$0} END{print line}' cop31.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk -F', ' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {
    if ($2 == "\"b\"") { 
        if (!var) {
            print
            var=1
        } else {
            var=""
        }
    } else {
        print
        var=""
    }
}' files.csv
```